# Xamarin: Set multiple viewmodels by reference from code behind

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I need to set two ViewModels from the code behind in the xaml code. Or if there is better way doing would be great to.

When I do it like this way the application crashes. When I set ProductDetailViewModel in the code behind (BindingContext = ViewModel) everything works fine.

**update**
It's not an good idea to pass viewModels as parameters.
I have now one class "ViewModelLocator" which contains all the ViewModels as static properties. Use Google for more info. This way things are way easier.

example
ViewModelLocator

```
public static class ViewModelLocator
{
     public static AddProductViewModel AddProductViewModel { get; set; } = new AddProductViewModel(App.ProductDataStore, App.NavigationService);
}
```

**end update**

**update 2**

As @Waescher stated, it's better to use FreshMvvm. The static approach is simple and fast but not good for slow devices or larger apps. Thanks.

**end update 2**

```
**Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException:** 'Position 9:10. Can not find the object referenced by `ProductDetailViewModel`'
```

Since I can't set the ViewModels directly in the xaml I need to do it by reference from code behind.

See  < *** First ViewModel *** > and < *** Second ViewModel *** > in the xaml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:BoerPlaza.Controls"
                 xmlns:flv="clr-namespace:DLToolkit.Forms.Controls;assembly=DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.FlowListView"
                 xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
                 x:Class="BoerPlaza.Views.Product.ProductCustomerPictures">
        <ContentPage.BindingContext>
            <x:Reference Name="ProductDetailViewModel" /><!-- *** First ViewModel ***!-->
        </ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout>
                <!-- Total image count -->
                <Label Text="{Binding Product.UserImages.Total}"
                       Style="{StaticResource H2}" />
                <!-- Title -->
                <Label Text="{Binding Product.Title}"
                       Style="{StaticResource H1}" />
                <!-- reviews -->
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <controls:StarDisplayTemplateView x:Name="customRattingBar"
                                                      SelectedStarValue="{Binding Product.RatingTotal}" />
                    <Label  Text="{Binding Product.RatingAmount, StringFormat='{0} reviews | '}" />
                    <Label Text="Schrijf een review" />
                </StackLayout>
    
                <Label Text="{Binding Product.Title, StringFormat='Heb je een productfoto van {0} die je wilt delen? '}" />
    
                <Button Text="Foto's toevoegen"
                        Command="{Binding SelectImagesCommand}"
                        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource neutral-color}"
                        BorderColor="{StaticResource alt-color}"
                        BorderWidth="1"
                        TextColor="{StaticResource primary-color}"
                        HorizontalOptions="Start"
                        HeightRequest="40"
                        FontSize="12" />
    
                <!-- hr -->
                <BoxView Style="{StaticResource separator}" />
    
                <flv:FlowListView FlowColumnCount="3"
                                  x:Name="listItems"
                                  FlowItemsSource="{Binding Media}"
                                  SeparatorVisibility="None"
                                  HasUnevenRows="false"
                                  RowHeight="100"
                                  HeightRequest="0">
                    <flv:FlowListView.BindingContext>
                        <x:Reference Name="MultiMediaPickerViewModel" /> <!-- *** Second ViewModel ***!-->
                    </flv:FlowListView.BindingContext>
                    <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <ffimageloading:CachedImage  DownsampleToViewSize="true"
                                                             HeightRequest="100"
                                                             Source="{Binding PreviewPath}"
                                                             Aspect="AspectFill"
                                                             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
                                <Image Source="play"
                                       IsVisible="false"
                                       HorizontalOptions="End"
                                       VerticalOptions="End">
                                    <Image.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger TargetType="Image"
                                                     Binding="{Binding Type}"
                                                     Value="Video">
                                            <Setter Property="IsVisible"
                                                    Value="True" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Image.Triggers>
                                </Image>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                </flv:FlowListView>
    
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
```

Code behind:

```
  [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ProductCustomerPictures : ContentPage
    {
    
        public ProductDetailViewModel ProductDetailViewModel
        {
            get { return _productDetailViewModel; }
            set { _productDetailViewModel = value; }
        }
    
        public MultiMediaPickerViewModel MultiMediaPickerViewModel
        {
            get { return _multiMediaPickerViewModel; }
            set { _multiMediaPickerViewModel = value; }
        }
    
    
        private ProductDetailViewModel _productDetailViewModel;
        private MultiMediaPickerViewModel _multiMediaPickerViewModel;
    
        public ProductCustomerPictures(ProductDetailViewModel viewModel)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ProductDetailViewModel = viewModel;
            MultiMediaPickerViewModel = new MultiMediaPickerViewModel(MultiMediaPickerServiceStaticVariableHolder.MultiMediaPickerService);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you think you can't set it in XAML? And what is this `ProductDetailViewModel `? Where does it come from?

Comment: From the previous view. When I do it like this the application crashes. When I set ProductDetailViewModel in the code behind everything works fine.

Comment: One update. It's not an good idea to pass viewModels as parameters.
I have now one class "ViewModelLocator" which has all ViewModels as static properties. I initialize them in my AppShell.xaml. Use Google for more info. This way things are way easier.

Comment: If you want to have my opinion: Don't pass viewModels as parameters and DON'T use that static approach. ViewModels might get huge in memory consumption. Instead of using View-To-View navigation, use ViewModel-To-ViewModel-Navigation. With this, you can easily wire things up with an IoC container. Do yourself a favor and check FreshMvvm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood this correctly and if you want to keep the pattern to pass in the view model as constructor argument ...

```
    public ProductCustomerPictures(ProductDetailViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ProductDetailViewModel = viewModel;
        MultiMediaPickerViewModel = new MultiMediaPickerViewModel(MultiMediaPickerServiceStaticVariableHolder.MultiMediaPickerService);
    }
```

... then you can remove this completely ...

```
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        ...
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

... and this property ...

```
    public ProductDetailViewModel ProductDetailViewModel
    {
        get { return _productDetailViewModel; }
        set { _productDetailViewModel = value; }
    }
```

Instead, just set the BindingContext directly in the constructor.

```
    public ProductCustomerPictures(ProductDetailViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel;    // <-- here
        MultiMediaPickerViewModel = new MultiMediaPickerViewModel(MultiMediaPickerServiceStaticVariableHolder.MultiMediaPickerService);
    }
```

Now, each and every control in the XAML is binding to the `ProductDetailViewModel`.

But you still have the FlowListView which should bind to the `MultiMediaPickerViewModel`. Instead of setting its binding context directly in XAML, it is common to use the binding with a reference, but first you have to give the whole page a name with which we can refer in the binding:

```
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        ...
        ...
        x:Name="thisPage"     <--- here
        x:Class="BoerPlaza.Views.Product.ProductCustomerPictures">
```

Now, you can use the name as reference in the binding expression:

```
    <flv:FlowListView FlowColumnCount="3"
        x:Name="listItems"
        FlowItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference thisPage}, Path=MultiMediaPickerViewModel.Media}"
        SeparatorVisibility="None"
        HasUnevenRows="false"
        RowHeight="100"
        HeightRequest="0">
```

`"{Binding Source={x:Reference thisPage}, Path=MultiMediaPickerViewModel.Media}"` uses the page itself (by name `thisPage`) and binds to the property `Media` of the property `MultiMediaPickerViewModel` of the page.

With that, you can safely remove this code as well:

```
    <flv:FlowListView.BindingContext>
        ...
    </flv:FlowListView.BindingContext>
```

---

By the way, you can condense the properties in the code behind:

```
    public MultiMediaPickerViewModel MultiMediaPickerViewModel { get; private set; }

    public ProductCustomerPictures(ProductDetailViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
        MultiMediaPickerViewModel = new MultiMediaPickerViewModel(MultiMediaPickerServiceStaticVariableHolder.MultiMediaPickerService);
    }
```